# Want to show 10 records in each class

Tags: php

I have 20 rows in my database and I have a header in the main page index.php in which I have Two class I want to show 10 records in one class and 10 records in another class. So please Help me guys Thanks In Advance

```
<li>
    <a href="index.php" class="parent"><span>Home</span></a>
    <div class="columns two">
        <?php 
            $qry = "SELECT `SectionId`, `Title` FROM `section`";
            $records = mysql_query($qry);
            $num_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($records) / 2;
            while($record= mysql_fetch_array($records))
            {
                ?>
                    <ul class="one">
                        <li>
                            <a href="department.php?sId=<?php echo $record['SectionId'];?>">
                                <span><?php echo $record['Title']; ?> </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="two">
                        <li>
                            <a href="department.php?sId=<?php echo $record['SectionId'];?>">
                                <span><?php echo $record['Title']; ?></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <?php 
            } 
        ?>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. For each row in the table, you're displaying two ULs, each with just one LI, and each of them showing the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li><a href="index.php" class="parent"><span>Home</span></a>
        <div class="columns two">
           <?php
                    $qry = "SELECT `SectionId`, `Title` FROM `section`";

                    $records = mysql_query($qry);

                    $num_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($records);

                    $m = 0;

                    while($record= mysql_fetch_array($records))
                    {
               if($m<10){
            ?>

            <ul class="one">

               <li>
                    <a href="department.php?sId=<?php echo $record['SectionId'];?>">
                        <span>
                            <?php
                                    echo $record['Title'];

                            ?>
                        </span>
                    </a>
               </li>
             </ul>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <ul class="two">

               <li>
                    <a href="department.php?sId=<?php echo $record['SectionId'];?>">
                        <span>
                            <?php
                                    echo $record['Title'];

                            ?>
                        </span>
                    </a>
               </li>
             </ul>
                <?php  } $m++;

                        }
                ?>
          </div>
      </li>
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better if we can remove `<ul>` from loop or executed just once for each ten products

Comment: isn't it possible that we can first show 10 rows in the first class named `class = 'one'`? and then show the other ten rows in class two i want to do this dynamically

Comment: It might be worth noting the poor choice of MySQL library... Remember that `mysql_*` functions are now deprecated, and it'd be prudent to mention that the OP should be using MySQLi or PDO...

Comment: if I remove <ul> then how can i loop the design?

Comment: Just use loop like <ul <?php if($m<10){?>class="one" <?php}else{?> class="two"<?php}?>>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $i=0;
while($record= mysql_fetch_array($records))
{
//your code here
$i++;
if($i%10==0)
{
 echo '<ul></ul>';
}
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<?php
$qry = "SELECT `SectionId`, `Title` FROM `section`";
$records = mysql_query($qry);
$num_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($records) / 2;
?>
        <ul class="one">
<?php
$nbrec=0;
while($record= mysql_fetch_array($records)) {
    if (++$nbrec == 10) {
    ?>
        </ul>
        <ul class="two">
    <?php
    }
    ?>
            <li>
                <a href="department.php?sId=<?php echo $record['SectionId'];?>">
                    <span><?php echo $record['Title']; ?> </span>
                </a>
            </li>
    <?php 
}
?>
        </ul>
```